# Restrict function template to specific types?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, sfinae

I want to make function that will make easy to concatenate string.
Let suppose I have `struct A`:

```
struct A {
    int a;
    double b;
}
```

Now i want to print like this:

```
A a = {1, 2.0};
cout << someString + string{"dsdassa"} + a;
```

or to concat string like this:

```
string s{"das"};
string s2 = s + A{1, 2.0f};
```

So i make function like this:

```
template <typename T>
std::string operator+(std::string & lhs, T && t)
{
    std::cout<< std::endl << "LOG" << '\t' << "operator+(std::string & lhs, T && t)" << std::endl;

    std::string neww(lhs);
    neww += ' ';
    neww += std::to_string(t);
    return neww;
}
```

For this function to work type `T` have to have `std::to_string` function specialized.

If I implement `std::to_string` for `A` like this:

```
 namespace std {
     std::string to_string(A & a)
     {
         return "a = " + std::toString(a.a) + ", b= " + std::to_string(a.b);
     }
 }
```

examples above will work.

Problem with this is that this will not work if I try to concat 2 strings like this: `cout << s + std::string{"blabla"};` because there is no `std::to_string` for `std::string`;

I think this could be solved if I somehow could restrict `operator+` function to types that have `std::to_string`.

Is it possible?

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to just `cout << someString << "dsdassa" << to_string(a);`

Comment: By the way, you can use `boost::to_string` which is more general (w.r.t. allowed types, including `std::string` itself).

Comment: also, in this contexts, why use `T&&`, `T const&` should do the job.

Comment: @BoPersson That's ok, but because of this `string s2 = s + A{1, 2.0f};`.
@alfC Because temporary values can't bind to T &.

Comment: @alfC You are actually right, `T const &` would be ok. I forgot to write const and it didn't worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The typical answer these days is this. To define the function with an extra template parameter that will make the function be ignored if the dummy type constructed from the expression doesn't exist.

```
template <typename T, typename = decltype(std::to_string(std::declval<T>()))>
std::string operator+(std::string & lhs, T && t)
{
...
}
```

It can be more refined by it does what you want.

Another more elegant syntax is this

```
template <typename T>
auto operator+(std::string & lhs, T && t) -> decltype(std::to_string(t)) 
{
...
}
```

This exploits a language feature called SFINAE.

Comment: What would I do if my type T needs to implement more than 1 function?
Multiple typename = ... ?

Comment: Put them before the one with `decltype`  `template <typename T, typename T2 = ..., typename T3 = ..., typename = decltype(std::to_string(std::declval<T>()))>` or use the second option.